# nested attributes update triggers wrong callback in observer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, observers

Two classes in the app/model:

```
class Job
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end

class Address
end
```

Then in `jobs_controller`, `update` method, I do `@job.update(job_params)`, address params included in the job_params from the form submission.

The address can be updated correctly, however the address observer does not behave properly. Instead `after_updated` be called, it actually triggers `after_create` when address gets updated.

```
address_observer.rb

# cannot be triggered when address gets updated
def after_update(address)
end

# can be triggered when address gets updated
def after_create(address)
end
```

Cannot figure it out why, anyone could give some help on this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you need to make sure your parameters are passed in with a key `address_attributes`, and the correct `id`. If you do not include the `id`, a record will be created. This is why `after_create` is firing instead of `after_update`.

Here's an example (assuming a `has_one` relation:)

```
{ job: { address_attributes: { id: 1, foo: 'bar' } } }
```

Here is the relevant documentation: [ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.1/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

> You can now set or update attributes on the associated posts through an attribute hash for a member: include the key :posts_attributes with an array of hashes of post attributes as a value.
>   For each hash that does not have an id key a new record will be instantiated [...]

Comment: thanks a lot! i just need to pass permit `id` in the controller params require.

Comment: also I didn't realize it created a new record every time because the address count in db does not change. I just read the console log carefully and figured out that rails actually deletes the old address and creates a new one with a new `id`.

Comment: @Shane: That's interesting. I didn't know about that behaviour, but will warn my colleagues about it.

Answer (score 0):

instead of observer..use callback in model...

```
after_commit :add_count_in_profile, on: :create


def add_count_in_profile
  Rails.logger.info  "---------updating images count in the profile for #
end
```